# CakePHP HTTP Client default proxy settings

Tags: php, http, cakephp, proxy, cakephp-3.0

My application is running behind a proxy at work. To get the CakePHP HTTP client to work I have to pass in my proxy settings. I am passing in the proxy settings every time I create a new HTTP client.

```
$http = new Client([
      "proxy" => [
        "proxy" => "MYPROXYURL",
        "username" => "MYUSERNAME",
        "password" => "MYPASSWORD"
      ]
]);
```

Is there a way to make these settings the default so I can keep my code more DRY? I was hoping this could be done in the bootstrap settings but if I had to I could extend the `Cake\Http\Client` class and use a custom wrapper. If I did that, which folder is best to put my custom Cake classes in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your own client class `YourClient extends Client`. And then either put the config directly into the `$_defaultConfig` or put a `Configure::read('App.http.client')` in the constructor and read the proxy values there from your configuration.

```
namespace App\Http;

use Cake\Http\Client as CakeClient;

class Client extends CakeClient { /*...*/ }
```

Then instantiate your own class instead of the core class you're inhereting any way.

Comment: Thanks, what would you suggest is a good directory to store my 'YourClient' class?

Comment: I usually mirror the core namespace in my app if I have to extend classes from it so it would be `App\Http\Client`. For more specific stuff I introduce new folders like `App\Navigation` and I put a lot under `App\Model\*` as well because most of the things are business logic related which is part of the model layer. But at the end of the day it's a matter of personal preference. I've updated my answer.